# Why does this function return {author: Robert C. Martin, likes: NaN} when larger array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
const mostLikes = (blogs) => {
  if (!blogs.length) {
    return 0
  }

  const distinctAuthors = [...new Set(blogs.map((blog) => blog.author))]
  const summer = (prev, comp) => prev.likes + comp.likes

  console.log(distinctAuthors)
  const dummyAuth = {
    author: 'hmm',
    likes: 0,
  }

  const authorsWithLikes = distinctAuthors.map((author) => ({
    author,
    likes: blogs.filter((n) => n.author === author).reduce(summer, dummyAuth),
  }))

  const reducer = (prev, comp) => (prev[1] > comp[1] ? prev : comp)
  return authorsWithLikes.reduce(reducer, authorsWithLikes[0])
}
```

works nomarlly when single blogs size === 1 but not when input is=>

```
  const blogs = [{
      _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',title: 'React patterns', author: 'Michael Chan', url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/', likes: 7, __v: 0,
    }, {
      _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8', title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful', author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', url: 'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html', likes: 5, __v: 0,
    }, {
      _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9', title: 'Canonical string reduction', author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra', url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html', likes: 12, __v: 0,
    }, {
      _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa', title: 'First class tests', author: 'Robert C. Martin', url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll', likes: 10, __v: 0,
    }, {
      _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb', title: 'TDD harms architecture', author: 'Robert C. Martin', url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html', likes: 0, __v: 0,
    }, {
      _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc', title: 'Type wars', author: 'Robert C. Martin', url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html', likes: 2, __v: 0,
    },
    ]
```

no idea what to do, have tried implementing different methods, but kind of hit a roadblock now. Wonder if there is better way also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the summer reducer. It expects an object containing a `likes` property. However, it's returning a number. The first time you call summer it receives the `dummyAuth` object which has a `likes` property, however, the second time its called it receives a number (that does not contain a like's property).

You can fix the problem by making summer return an object with a `likes` property.

```js
const mostLikes = (blogs) => {
  if (!blogs.length) {
    return 0;
  }

  const distinctAuthors = [...new Set(blogs.map((blog) => blog.author))];
  const summer = (prev, comp) => ({ likes: prev.likes + comp.likes });

  const dummyAuth = {
    author: 'hmm',
    likes: 0,
  }

  const authorsWithLikes = distinctAuthors.map((author) => ({
    author,
    likes: blogs.filter((n) => n.author === author).reduce(summer, dummyAuth ).likes, // note: you have to access the `likes` property 
  }));

  const reducer = (prev, comp) => (prev[1] > comp[1] ? prev : comp);
  return authorsWithLikes.reduce(reducer, authorsWithLikes[0]);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have undeclared variable `author`:

```
blogs.filter((n) => n.author === author)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here `dummyAuth` is type object and code was trying to add a number with object. Instead of declaring `dummyAuth` as object only initialize `likes` with 0

```js
const blogs = [{
  _id: '5a422a851b54a676234d17f7',
  title: 'React patterns',
  author: 'Michael Chan',
  url: 'https://reactpatterns.com/',
  likes: 7,
  __v: 0,
}, {
  _id: '5a422aa71b54a676234d17f8',
  title: 'Go To Statement Considered Harmful',
  author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
  url: 'http://www.u.arizona.edu/~rubinson/copyright_violations/Go_To_Considered_Harmful.html',
  likes: 5,
  __v: 0,
}, {
  _id: '5a422b3a1b54a676234d17f9',
  title: 'Canonical string reduction',
  author: 'Edsger W. Dijkstra',
  url: 'http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~EWD/transcriptions/EWD08xx/EWD808.html',
  likes: 12,
  __v: 0,
}, {
  _id: '5a422b891b54a676234d17fa',
  title: 'First class tests',
  author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/05/05/TestDefinitions.htmll',
  likes: 10,
  __v: 0,
}, {
  _id: '5a422ba71b54a676234d17fb',
  title: 'TDD harms architecture',
  author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2017/03/03/TDD-Harms-Architecture.html',
  likes: 0,
  __v: 0,
}, {
  _id: '5a422bc61b54a676234d17fc',
  title: 'Type wars',
  author: 'Robert C. Martin',
  url: 'http://blog.cleancoder.com/uncle-bob/2016/05/01/TypeWars.html',
  likes: 2,
  __v: 0,
}, ]

const mostLikes = (blogs) => {
  if (!blogs.length) {
    return 0
  }

  const distinctAuthors = [...new Set(blogs.map((blog) => blog.author))];
  const summer = (prev, comp) => prev + comp.likes;
  const likes = 0;

  const authorsWithLikes = distinctAuthors.map((author) => {
    return {
      author,
      likes: blogs.filter((n) => n.author === author).reduce(summer, likes)
    };
  });
  console.log(authorsWithLikes);
  const reducer = (prev, comp) => (prev[1] > comp[1] ? prev : comp);
  return authorsWithLikes.reduce(reducer, authorsWithLikes[0])
};
mostLikes(blogs)
```